# How to connect two windows together? One window follows the behavior of the second window

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a problem. I'm writing a python program and I don't know how to connect two windows together. I will define it like this:

- first window `a` - for example notepad.
- second window `b` - for example calculator.

I would like window `b` to be "glued" under window `a`.
Minimizing the `a` window. window `b` should be minimized. Same behavior when maximizing.
I want window `b` to follow the movements of window `a`. I tried this way:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

window_a= Application().connect(title="notepad", timeout=10)
window_b= Application().connect(title="calc", timeout=10)

def anchor_windows(window_a, window_b):
    window_b = window_b.top_level_parent()
    state_window_a = window_a.get_show_state()
    state_window_b = window_b.get_show_state()

    if state_window_a == 2 and state_window_b == 1 or state_window_a== 2 and state_window_b == 3:
        window_b.minimize()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return False
    if state_window_a == 3 and state_window_b == 2 or state_window_a == 1 and state_window_b == 2:
        window_b.maximize()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        window_a.set_focus()
        return True

    return True if state_window_a == 3 and state_window_b == 3 else False
```